# "this" in JavaScript. reference to an object inside a factory

Tags: javascript, oop, reference, this

I wrote some classes in javascript and i wrote a few FunctionFactories for them. But I think that i have done some things wrong.

I renamed some things of my code, that you can understand it better.

So the first class is the "root"-class. this class has children, which i add later.

```
function templateRoot(){
    this.id = "root";
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];

    this.editable = true; // bla

    this.render = function(){
        $.each(this.children,function(i,obj){
            this.children[i].render();
            var baseButtons = this.getBaseButtons();
            $('#'+this.id).append(baseButtons);
        });
    };
    this.addBase = addBaseFactory(this);
};
```

The attribute "addBase" gets a function which is delivered by addBaseFactory...

```
function addBaseFactory(that){
    return function(){
        var newBase = new base(that.children.length, that.id);
        that.children.push(newBase);
    };
}
```

...and the base class which is used to generate a object in "addBase" looks like this:

```
function base(count, parent){
    this.id = parent+"_base"+count;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.children = [];
    this.remove = function (){
        $('#'+this.id).remove();        
    };
    this.render = baseRenderFactory(this);
    this.addChild = addChildFactory(this);
    this.getBaseButtons = function(){
        var addAttributeButton = new $("<button>+ Attribute</button>").button();
        var addTextButton = new $("<button>+ Text</button>").button();
        return [addAttributeButton, addTextButton];
    };
}
```

The problem now is. When i debug the code and set a breakpoint within the "render" function of the root-object. Then i can see, that "this" is not the root but the "base" object. And i cannot figure out why it is like that because the "root" object is the owner of this function, and my base has an own render function which is not called directly there.

So even the "this" in the line

```
$.each(this.children,function(i,obj){
```

Refers to the "base" object. But the "this" is inside the "root" object...

Hope you can help me :-)

---

**EDIT:**

*The code to let it run:*

```
var test = new templateRoot();
test.addBase();
test.render();
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

"that" in "addBaseFactory" refers to the correct "base" object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your explanation pretty confusing, so I may have misinterpreted what you're trying to do, but I *think* you expect `this` within your nested functions to the same object as the `this` in the outer `templateRoot()` function. That's not how `this` works in JavaScript. Nested functions don't inherit the same `this` as the containing function - each function has its own `this` object that is set depending on how the function is called.

Here's one possible solution, which uses the fact that nested functions can see variables from their containing function(s):

```
function templateRoot(){
    var self = this; // save a reference to this for use in nested functions
    this.id = "root";
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];

    this.editable = true; // bla

    this.render = function(){
        $.each(self.children,function(i,obj){
            self.children[i].render();
            var baseButtons = this.getBaseButtons();
            $('#'+self.id).append(baseButtons);
        });
    };
    this.addBase = addBaseFactory(this);
};
```

A detailed explanation about how `this` works in JS can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried your solution and debugged it. the problem is the "self" referes to "window" here.

Comment: That's weird. If you call `templateRoot()` using the `new` operator then its `this` will be the new object being created and thus `self` will also be that object. If you call it _without_ the `new` operator then `this` would be `window` (and thus so would `self`).

Comment: Seeing this is a scope issue and jQuery is being used, wouldn't `$.proxy` resolve all of the problems mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this render its childerens children, since jquery would send each child as this?

```
this.render = function(){
    $.each(this.children,function(i,obj){
        this.children[i].render();
        var baseButtons = this.getBaseButtons();
        $('#'+this.id).append(baseButtons);
    });
};
```

Btw in what scope is addBaseFactory called? Because I think the "this"  in the base, will refer to that scope.

Comment: i've wrote something in my question (EDIT)